# Esper EPL statement each time an Id has raised more than by the value one

Tags: esper, epl

I am looking for an EPL statement which fires an event each time the Id of the current message of my stream has raised more than one. Like (a+1 != b).

Something like this but I do not know the right syntax:

```
select * from pattern[a=test.SensorEvent(ids) -> b=test.SensorEvent(ids)(a+1!=b)];
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into match-recognize if you have frequent matches. Patterns are for less-frequent matches as they work off indexes on search criteria and maintaining indexes is an expense.

The expression is similar to `temperature > a.temperature` or `temperature > (a.temperature + 1)`